# Set required props on component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say that I create a custom component like this:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => (
  <div
    className={props.name}
    id={props.id}>
    {props.children}
  </div>
)
```

And I **need** to make sure that `props` contain the variables `name` and `id`, because otherwise what I want to do is not going to work (now I know that this code will work anyhow, but hypothetically say that it won't).

Is there a way in React to *demand* that certain props are passed to a component?

Maybe this is something that is obvious, but I couldn't find any information about it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use PropTypes. It was earlier a part of React but now it has its own npm package, https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types. This will give you a runtime error if ther props are not provided. Its also useful, because linters can warn you if you miss them.
https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/prop-types.md

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; 

const MyComponent = (props) => (
  <div
    className={props.name}
    id={props.id}>
    {props.children}
  />
);

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  element: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.element).isRequired
};
```